# Remove Duplicate entry from a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a mail variable with content like this

```
if ($user -eq 'abc') {$mail += 'abc@ae.com;'}
elseif ($user -eq 'efg') {$mail += 'efg@ae.com;'}
elseif ($user -eq 'hij') {$mail += 'hij@ae.com;'}
elseif ($user -eq 'klm') {$mail += 'klm@ae.com;'}
```

Now the $mail variable will have content like this
`abc@ae.com;klm@ae.com;abc@ae.com;hij@ae.com;klm@ae.com`

How do i remove the duplicate mail from $mail variable. tried the below but no luck.

```
$mail = $mail | select -unique
$mail | sort | Get-Unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split` + `Select-Object -Unique` do the job

```
("abc@ae.com;klm@ae.com;abc@ae.com;hij@ae.com;klm@ae.com".Split(';') |Select-Object -Unique) -join ";"
```

you could use directly linq:

```
$arr = "abc@ae.com;klm@ae.com;abc@ae.com;hij@ae.com;klm@ae.com".Split(";")
[Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct($arr) -join ";"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `-split` operator to get an array of mails, then use the `Select-Object -unique` cmdlet to remove the duplicates and finally join the array back to the desired string:

```
('abc@ae.com;klm@ae.com;abc@ae.com;hij@ae.com;klm@ae.com' -split ';' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ';'
```

**Output:**

```
abc@ae.com;klm@ae.com;hij@ae.com
```